# Shell and ssh locale issues on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ssh, locale

I'm trying to configure my Raspbian to support console output in my native language (Polish). After updating my locale preferences (I chose `pl_PL.UTF-8` as my default locale), I ran a test - I typed some non-ASCII characters needed to represent strings in Polish, and saved them into a file:

[image]

It seems the default font doesn't support UTF-8, I guess... I downloaded the file and viewed it in a text editor on my Windows machine:

[image]

Well, that's exactly what I typed. But when I view the file via the SSH console (PuTTY), this is what I see:

[image]

How do I set a UTF-8-compatible font in the "physical" Raspbian console and how do I set up the SSH connection to display the characters properly?

**EDIT:**
I should make it clear that the problem touches all the console output, not only text file contents. This is the lower part of `nano`'s CLI interface:

[image]

And below are the correct spellings, taken from some other remote Ubuntu instance:

[image]

The same happens to any translated command line tool I run.

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks to Steve Robillard, I set the remote character set in PuTTY to UTF-8, and now all the characters in my SSH console display properly. I didn't think it could be PuTTY's fault, because it was always working correctly with all the other machines I usually SSH into. I also thought the encoding is negotiated automatically... Wrong!

The problem with Raspberry's "physical" console (the one displayed on the screen connected directly via HDMI), however, **still remains unsolved**.

**EDIT 3:**
Answeing HeatfanJohn's request, here is the output of `locale -a`:

[image]

Comment: Assuming all of this is done through Putty have you checked what font putty is using? If not check the putty window translation section - it has an option for the remote character set.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, all console screenshots are from PuTTY (except for the first image - that's a screen connected directly to Raspberry). My instance of PuTTy uses `Courier New` font, which supports all the characters I need.

Comment: @SteveRobillard: And the Translation section had a `remote character set` setting, which did the trick! Thank you, I now have localized console via SSH :)

Comment: I suggest you write an answer to  your own question and accept it. Glad I could help.

Comment: What does `locale -a` display?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

What does `locale` (without the -a) report (i.e. all the language specific variables and their current values)? I think you should ensure that you have done:

```
export LANG=pl_PL.utf8
export LANGUAGE=pl_PL.utf8`
```

in your `.bashrc` I believe.